# Issue appending html content to newly generated script

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I asked a similar question recently to this but I think it lacked clarity so I will try and draft it better below and hopefully I'll get an answer or some additional help.

I am dynamically generating a script tag with JSON data which will append HTML content which is currently on the page.

Code is below. The issue is that the JSON is only adding one of the paragraphs on to each of the List Headings in this newly created script. All paragraphs under each List Heading should be added  for each.

Here's the Javscript:

```
            //Question headers & Paragraph Answers

            var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

            scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "application/ld+json");

            var start = '{"@context": "https://schema.org","@type": "TestPage","mainEntity": [';
            var end = ']}';
            var headings = document.querySelectorAll(".list-test .accordion");
            var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll(".panel > p");
            var headElement = document.querySelector("header");

            scriptTag.prepend(start);

            for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < headings.length && j < paragraphs.length; i++, j++) {
              scriptTag.append('{"@type": "Question", "name": "' + headings[i].innerHTML + ' ", ');
              scriptTag.append('"acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "' + paragraphs[j].innerHTML.trim() + ' "}}, ');
            }

            scriptTag.append(end);

            headElement.append(scriptTag);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
            <section class="row text-center list-test">
              <h2>
                Test List
              </h2>
              <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 1
              </p>
              <div class="panel">
                <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  <p>
                    Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
              </div>
              <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 2</p>
              <div class="panel">
                <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  <p>
                    Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
              </div>
              <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 3</p>
              <div class="panel">
                <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  <p>
                    Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Para 4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
              </div>
              <p class="accordion accordian-type">List Header 4</p>
              <div class="panel">
                <p>Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  <p>
                    Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  </p>
                  Para 4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                </p>
                <p>
                  Para 5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
```

Here's the generated JSON at the moment:

```
            <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context": "https://schema.org","@type": "TestPage","mainEntity": [{"@type": "Question", "name": "List Header 1
                                 ", "acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "}}, {"@type": "Question", "name": "List Header 2 ", "acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "Para 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "}}, {"@type": "Question", "name": "List Header 3 ", "acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "Para 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "}}, {"@type": "Question", "name": "List Header 4 ", "acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "Para 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco "}}, ]}</script>
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to append the correct content in the newly generated JSON that would great eg. the 3 paragraphs under the list heading 1 to append on to the text for the first answer in the JSON, the 2 paragraphs appended to append to the text for the second answer in the JSON etc.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just parse the JSON into an object literal?

Comment: i think it's an issue with the loop, if anyone has a suggestion for refactoring the above code to append the correct content or have other suggested edits that would be great, thanks

Comment: You need to have 2 for loops nested

Comment: Please just use Javascript object and then JSON.stringify

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to edit the code to show where the changes should be - can you let me know what the structure of the 2 for loops should be - is it this ? for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < headings.length && j < paragraphs.length; i++, j++) {
              scriptTag.append('{"@type": "Question", "name": "' + headings[i].innerHTML + ' ", ');
for (j = 0;j < paragraphs.length; j++) {
              scriptTag.append('"acceptedAnswer": {"@type": "Answer","text": "' + paragraphs[j].innerHTML.trim() + ' "}}, ');
            }
}